# iOS Firebase Crash reporting and mixed project (Objective-C + Swift) - reports are always for "main" function, so non-informative

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase-crash-reporting

I've discovered this issue in several projects:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new Xcode project with **Objective-C** language (BitCode disabled)
2. Go to
   Firebase console and create a new iOS app
3. Setup Firebase Crash
   Reporting using Cocoapods
4. Add some **Swift** code, for example
   **ViewController.swift**
5. Then, make a crash somwhere in swift code
   (for example, inside a button action)

Foe example:

```
let array = [42]
let outOfBounds = array[100500]
```

or just

`fatalError("error")`

it doesn't matter.

6) Few minutes later you will got a crash report named:

> main (main.m:14)

[image: Formatted picture]

I mean, it always says "main(): %some line% and [NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:]" , despite file/line where exception has been raised (and despite the type of error, it always "doesNotRecognizeSelector")

As you can see, symbol files were uploaded successfully (report is symbolicated)
I've checked build options and compiler flags - no luck.

Here are code samples if needed:

> AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [FIRApp configure];

    return YES;
}
```

> ViewController.swift:

```
@IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {

    let array = [42]
    let outOfBounds = array[100500]

}
```

**Notice**
If you create the same Xcode project, but using Swift only - reports will be "more informative":

[image]

And same for clean Objective-C project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the stack trace of the process when it crashed.

> I mean, it always says "main(): %some line%", despite file/line where
>   exception has been raised

The process has to start at `main`. See line number 3 and you will know that the crash is caused because of an unrecognized selector. You can also see the screen where it crashed like this

[image]

I don't think you can get more information than this. If your app is on TestFlight or Appstore you can check the crash from Xcode directly. Make sure the account from which you uploaded is added to Xcode. Go to `Windows->Organizer` and click on the Crashes tab. Select your application from the list in the left side. Now you'll have a list of crashes. Click on the crash you want to analyze, click on `Open in project` and select your project. Xcode will open the line where your code crashed.

Check [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs) link to learn more about reading error logs.

Comment: Don't forget: it might take up to 3 working days until the logs will be made available. Furthmore, the user's device has to have "sending diagnosis data" enabled.

Comment: I have updated my question for you. TL;TR: I'm getting more information if projects is Swift-only or Obj-C-only. And only for mixed projects I'm receiving "doesNotRecognizeSelector" everytime, even if it was caused by NSRangeException

Comment: What if you try to write a try catch around the main and log the exception yourself, would it be different from the exception from Firebase?